# Permission denied error when cloning a private GitHub repository

Tags: github, ssh-keys, cloud9-ide

I have a cloud9 repository on AWS and I would like to clone a github repository into it.  I have followed the documentation instructions of copying the http link on github and running this command:

```
git clone git@github.com:[my repo]
```

I get this error message when running the command:

```
Cloning into 'pm-tool'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does the user name on git have to match the user name on the AWS environment?  Any suggestions for troubleshooting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t upload your GitHub login to anywhere as a general rule.

You need to grab/create a key from AWS, then save in your GitHub repo as a deploy key.

1. Get your [Cloud9 key](https://c9.io/account/ssh).
2. Add it to GitHub here: https://github.com/[user/org]/[repo_name]/settings/keys.

See: https://community.c9.io/t/public-ssh-key-needed/1315/3

Comment: Step 1 seems to be linked to the traditional Cloud9 service.  I am trying to use Cloud9 from within and AWS EC2 instance.  In this case, where can I get the SSH key.  I don't seem to have the same menu choices as the traditional Cloud9 service.

Comment: Is it because I set up my Cloud9 environment to be an EC2 environment.  These are the two options I had when setting up the environment:         Environment typeInfo
Choose between creating a new EC2 instance for your new environment or connecting directly to your server over SSH.

Create a new instance for environment (EC2)
Launch a new instance in this region to run your new environment.

Connect and run in remote server (SSH)
Display instructions to connect remotely over SSH and run your new environment.

Comment: I haven’t used that myself so I’m not sure, but if you’re within an EC2 instance, then you just need to create a key pair for your EC2 instance instead of getting it from Cloud9: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair

Comment: I have a .pem file but I don't see a way to convert that into an RSA key that Cloud9 seems to want as a deploy key?  I have contacted AWS support to see if they can help.